# why doesn't Integer.parseInt method work for splitted strings?

Tags: java, string, split, parseint

I'm trying to extract numbers from strings with specific format using String split method . 
then i want to get the numbers as int type using Integer parseInt method . 
here is a sample code which doesn't work . can somebody help me with this please?

```
String g = "hi5hi6";

String[] l = new String[2];
l = g.split("hi");

for (String k : l) {
    int p=Integer.parseInt(k);
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:36)
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code and see what is happening?

Comment: it works for splitted Strings, it just doesn't work for empty Strings, as your error message says, because an empty String is not a valid numerical value

Comment: The simplest solution would be to check if the string `k` is empty inside of the loop before parsing it.

Comment: @Stultuske but rigth above the loop,when I print k, non of them are empty.the error points to line ((int p=Integer ....))

Comment: FWIW, there is a good explanation on quirks of `String.split()` in Guava docs: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#splitter

Comment: @user12648660 "For input string: "" " states that at least one (in this case the first) value you try to parse is empty.

Comment: Next time put a `System.out.println(k);` prior to the parsing line. My personal preference to add some surrounding characters too, `System.out.println("*"+k+"*");`, so I do not have to notice empty lines, and I also see if there is extra whitespace for any reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is likely that the `String#split` is leaving your array with one or more empty elements.  Just filter those out and it should work:

```
String g = "hi5hi6";
String[] parts = g.split("hi");

for (String part : parts) {
    if (!part.isEmpty()) {
        int p = Integer.parseInt(part);
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
5
6
```

Comment: `!"".equals(part)` looks weird. Why don't just use `isEmpty()`? As far as I know `split` won't ever return null elements in the array.

Comment: Um...mine is the earlier one.

Comment: `answered 13 mins ago`

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen sorryyyyyyyy  I made a mistake you're right  it sorts "oldest" u are earlier .thanks again

Answer (score 2):

These are the elements in your array `[, 5, 6]`
you see the issue ? The first element is Empty.

Try this:

```
String[] l = new String[2];
l = g.split("hi");

for (String k : l) {
    if (!k.isEmpty()) {
        int p=Integer.parseInt(k);
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: it fixed the problem,thanks a lot.I got whats happening

Comment: @user12648660 yes you can accept only one answer !!

Answer (score -1):

Integer.ParseInt will always give you a Numberformat Exception if its not formatted. Its a UnChecked Exception so programmer Should handle this.

```
 String g="hi5hi6";
 String[] l=new String[2];
 l=g.split("hi");

 for(String k:l){
   try
   {
      if (!part.isEmpty()) {
         //the String to int conversion happens here
         int p=Integer.parseInt(k.trim());
         //print out the value after the conversion
         System.out.println(p);
     }
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
  {
     System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
  }

}
```

Comment: [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) **is an unchecked exception**, hence does not have to be handled by the programmer. A down-vote for an incorrect answer. Any class that derives from `RuntimeException` is an unchecked exception.